# How do I install ffmpeg for use with php on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: php, windows, 64-bit, windows-server-2008, ffmpeg

I have zend server running php on Windows Server 2008 64 bit. How do I install ffmpeg for use with php?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's the problem with "installing" it? Most versions of ffmpeg are static binaries that you just copy somewhere.

Comment: After some reflection, voting for migration to Superuser.

Answer (score 0):

I installed [Miro Video Converter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/) which installs ffmpeg with it and then just use the command line to run ffmpeg. You can use PHP to call command line functions.